# Image libraries sites to download pro images with no credits expiration policy

Tags: images, library

I found professional image libraries sites like http://www.istockphoto.com or http://www.dreamstime.com are quite useful to add some cool images to a website either when filling its contents or when designing its graphic layout.

Unfortunately both of the site I listed above use credits plans that expires after 12 months: you buy credits (using real bucks) and then you can download images, but if you don't use all the credits within 1 year, thay *suck* them out from your virtual wallet (I think it's really unfair, but too bad for you, that's their policy).

**Do you know about other good image libraries sites (from your real life experience) that use credits to download images, but thay don't expire after 12 months?**

Obviously I won't ignore your suggestions about any other image libraries sites.

Comment: Yea, I really hate that. It really screws over non-regular shoppers, since you can't put in exactly the amount that you need, so any time you make a purchase, you're guaranteed to have a few credits left over. I guess it's a tactic to get users to continually buy stock art (even when you don't need any), or let your credits go to waste.

Comment: @John Conde: I'm clueless about why you removed the tags "website design", "graphic".

Answer (score 1):

[PhotoDune](http://photodune.net/) (from Envato, same company as ThemeForest and CodeCanyon, etc). You can buy items without making a deposit, but they charge you a $2 premium to do so.

Comment: it's a small library, I tried some searches, but it provides really few pictures.

Answer (score -3):

At Dreamstime.com your credits don't expire. That's what I've been using and they have a big selection.

Comment: Welcome to webmasters. Dreamstime.com is mentioned in the question as being a site where credits expire. The questioner is looking for an alternative to them. I just checked and their site says they are valid for a year.